# How do I create Vue instance with Jest (Vue is not defined)

Tags: vue.js, jestjs

I want to test a code using Vue and jQuery.

It uses jQuery to call REST-API and the result(json) is processed by Vue.

But it's not correct.

When I ran the test I received an error like this

```
  ReferenceError: Vue is not defined

  32 |         },
  33 |         _show : function(_data){
  34 |             _data = "";
> 35 |             _data = new Vue({
     |                          ^
  36 |                 el : "#_elem",
  37 |                 data : {
  38 |                     result : _data
```

Are there any settings or descriptions missing?
Below is the source code.

The test code is not complete because of an error

**hoge.js**

```js
// hoge.js
var _hogehoge = {
    _ajaxCall : {
        _getHogeInfo : function(){
            return $.ajax({
                url: "http://xxxxxxx/yyyyy",
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'GET',
                data: {param: "001"},
                crossDomain: true,
                cache: false,
                xhrFields: {
                    withCredentials: true
                }
            });
        }
    },
    _action : {
        _initiate : function(){
            _hogehoge._ajaxCall._getHogeInfo().done(function(_data){
                _hogehoge._action._show(_data);
            }).fail(function(e){
                _data = "";
                _data = new Vue({
                    el : "#_elem",
                    data : {
                        return : _data
                    }
                })
            });
        }
    },
    _show : function(_data){
        _data = "";
        _data = new Vue({
            el : "#_elem",
            data : {
                return : _data
            },
            // ・・・
        })
    }
};
```

**hoge.test.js**

```js
// hoge.test.js
const hoge = require('./hoge.js');
const _hoge = hoge.__get__('_hogehoge');
const jQuery = require("jquery");
 
jest.mock("jquery", () => {
  const mock = jest.genMockFromModule("jquery");
  const jq = jest.requireActual("jquery"); 
  mock.mockImplementation(() => jq("#_elem"));
  return mock;
});
global.$ = jQuery;
 
describe("start jest testing", () => {
    beforeAll(() => {
      document.body.innerHTML = `<p id="_elem" data-url="example.com">Hello world</p>`;
      jQuery.ajax.mockClear();
      jQuery.mockClear();
 
      const xhr = {
        done: jest.fn((cb) => {
          cb('{"aaaa":"bbb"}');
          return xhr;
        }),
        fail: jest.fn((cb) => {
          cb("test");
          return xhr;
        }),
      };
      jQuery.ajax.mockReturnValue(xhr);
      _hoge._action._initiate();
    });
 
    it("sample test", () => {
      console.log(document.body.innerHTML)
      // expect(not yet);
    });
  });
```

Comment: It obviously relies on global `Vue`. Provide it the same way you did with jQuery.

Comment: @EstusFlask Thank you for answering.
I'm actually trying, but the method may be wrong
I added the following code under `global.$ = jQuery;`, I will get an error at ajax.
`global.$ = require("vue");`

Comment: It should be `global.Vue = require("vue")`. Which error? There shouldn't be AJAX at all, all requests are supposed to be mocked in tests, unless proven otherwise.

Comment: @EstusFlask Thank you so much! The problem has been solved. I will take the next step.I made a mistake in the definition`global.$ = require("vue");`If you leave it as an answer, I would like to accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's expected that `Vue` is global variable rather than an import, it needs to be provided the same way as `$`:

```
global.Vue = require("vue")
```